# _changes API not working with filter and view parameter on Couchbase Lite

Tags: javascript, http, couchdb, couchbase-lite

The ***_changes*** document is not clear on the `filter` and `view` parameters, in Couchbase Lite. I am trying to query the below url to fetch changes if a document with type order gets added.

```
_changes?include_docs=true&feed=longpoll&since=0&filter=_view&view=orders%2Forder
```

This `filter=_view&view=orders%2Forder` query parameter is the issue, removing the same from the above fetches all the documents

Using the above gives a 404 on Couchbase Lite but the same works on CouchDB.
Response:

```
{
    status: 404,
    error: "not_found"
}
```

Here is my _design/orders

```
{
     "_id": "_design/orders",
     "language": "javascript",
     "views": {
          "order": {
               "map": "function(doc) {if(doc.type && doc.type == 'order') {emit(doc.oID, doc);}}"
           }
      }
}
```

Please can any one share a syntax or example on how to pass the design document and/or view in _changes API to get a filtered output.

Comment: Did you ask this question on the forums?  I remember seeing it before.

Comment: Yes I have asked this on CouchBase forums.

Answer (score 0):

Everyone who finds this, I think the answer could be changing the filter itself and the query string like this:

Filter:

```
{
 "_id": "_design/orders",
 "language": "javascript",
 "filters": {
      "order": "function(doc) {if(doc.type && doc.type == 'order') {emit(doc.oID, doc);}}"
  }
}
```

and the query string:

```
_changes?include_docs=true&feed=longpoll&since=0&filter=orders/order
```